# SharePoint REST API Call returns result as block of array

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a REST API call in SharePoint and everything is working as expected, however the output returned by call is array of array if more then 100 records are fetched (attached image):

[image: Output from rest api call]

I am not sure how to handle it, means result can be less then 100 or more then 100. Need some advice here.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add below code in success function of REST API call:

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(data) {
      if(data && data.d.results) {
          for(var i=0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
             console.log(data.d.results[i].Id);
          } 
      } 
   },
   error: function (error) {
      failure(error);
   } 
});
```

Comment: Hi @Vijay, have you tried this? is it working for you? let me know if you have any issue while using this.